# Grouping multidimensional array by two values

Tags: php

I have arrays like this.

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [transactioncurrencyid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => US Dollar
                [!] => {041E3DC9-D938-DD11-982C-0013724C58B7}
            )

        [smi_processingmonth] => Array
            (
                [!date] => 6/1/2011
                [!time] => 2:27 PM
                [!] => 2011-06-01T14:27:00-07:00
            )

        [smi_cchistoryid] => {678C5036-9EAA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
        [smi_includeindeal] => Array
            (
                [!name] => No
                [!] => 0
            )

                  [smi_locationid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => 1134 Hooksett Rd
                [!] => {5CC1585B-91AA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
            )
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [transactioncurrencyid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => US Dollar
                [!] => {041E3DC9-D938-DD11-982C-0013724C58B7}
            )


        [smi_processingmonth] => Array
            (
                [!date] => 5/1/2011
                [!time] => 2:27 PM
                [!] => 2011-05-01T14:27:00-07:00
            )

        [smi_cchistoryid] => {688C5036-9EAA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
        [smi_includeindeal] => Array
            (
                [!name] => No
                [!] => 0
            )

        [smi_locationid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => 1134 Hooksett Rd
                [!] => {5CC1585B-91AA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
            )
    )
```

How can i group them by location id then by smi_processingmonth

So I get something like this

```
[1134 Hooksett Rd] => Array
    (
        [ 5/1/2011] = array(
            [transactioncurrencyid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => US Dollar
                [!] => {041E3DC9-D938-DD11-982C-0013724C58B7}
            )


            [smi_processingmonth] => Array
                (
                    [!date] => 5/1/2011
                    [!time] => 2:27 PM
                    [!] => 2011-05-01T14:27:00-07:00
                )

            [smi_cchistoryid] => {688C5036-9EAA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
            [smi_includeindeal] => Array
                (
                    [!name] => No
                    [!] => 0
                )

            [smi_locationid] => Array
                (
                    [!name] => 1134 Hooksett Rd
                    [!] => {5CC1585B-91AA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}

             )
           )
         [1/1/2011] = array(
          [transactioncurrencyid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => US Dollar
                [!] => {041E3DC9-D938-DD11-982C-0013724C58B7}
            )

        [smi_processingmonth] => Array
            (
                [!date] => 6/1/2011
                [!time] => 2:27 PM
                [!] => 2011-06-01T14:27:00-07:00
            )

        [smi_cchistoryid] => {678C5036-9EAA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
        [smi_includeindeal] => Array
            (
                [!name] => No
                [!] => 0
            )

                  [smi_locationid] => Array
            (
                [!name] => 1134 Hooksett Rd
                [!] => {5CC1585B-91AA-E111-88E0-00155D010302}
            )
            )
    )
```

I have tried

```
   foreach($array as $keys)
                {

                    $key =  $keys['smi_processingmonth']['!date'];;
                    if (!isset($groups[$key])) 
                    {
                        $groups[$key] =  array($keys);
                    } else {
                        $groups[$key][] = $keys;
                    }
                }
                $newGroups = array();

                if(is_array($groups))
                {
                    foreach($groups as $cats => $values)
                    {

                        foreach($values as $itemValues){
                            $st = rtrim(trim($itemValues['smi_locationid']['!']));
                                $key = $st;
                                if (!isset($newGroups[$key])) 
                                {
                                    $newGroups[$key] = array($groups);

                                } else {
                                    $newGroups[$key][] = $itemValues;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking from Johan with a few modifications:

- avoid ltrim if already using trim
- put in a function, I can use temporary variables to maintain readability
- add a final **[]**, to avoid nasty $name/$date collision, out of original request, but safer

> ```
> function compactArray($data)
> {
>     $new_structure = array();
>     foreach ( $data as $row ) 
>       {
>         $name = trim($row['smi_locationid']['!name']);
>         $date = trim($row['smi_processingmonth']['!date']);
>         $new_structure[ $name ][ $date ][] = $row;
>     }
>     return $new_structure;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ehm, i have not tested it. But isn't it just:

```
$new_structure = array();
foreach ( $data as $row ) {
  $key1 = rtrim(trim($row['smi_locationid']['!name']));
  $key2 = rtrim(trim($row['smi_processingmonth']['!date']));
  $new_structure[$key1][$key2] = $row;
}
```

This code could use some isset()s, but i decided to keep them out for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The following produces your desired output array, correctly sorted:

```
function transaction_datecmp($tran1, $tran2)
{
   return strtotime($tran1['smi_processingmonth']['!']) -
          strtotime($tran2['smi_processingmonth']['!']);
}

$output_arr = array();
foreach ($input_arr as $transaction) {
   $location = $transaction['smi_locationid']     ['!name'];
   $date     = $transaction['smi_processingmonth']['!date'];
   $output_arr[$location][$date] = $transaction;
}
ksort($output_arr); // sorts by location
foreach ($output_arr as &$transaction_arr) {
   uasort($transaction_arr, 'transaction_datecmp');
}
```

Your data structure relies on the assumption that there cannot be two transactions on the same day, which is a somewhat dangerous assumption. Also using a location as a key is far from ideal (because of spelling, location changes, etc.) - unless it really should group things, like for paper mailing.

Data cleanup, like `trimm`ing strings, should be done beforehand, ideally at data input time.